# How to install Jack bindings for Haskell on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal, jack

I'm trying to setup the Jack bindings for Haskell (see https://www.stackage.org/package/jack and http://hackage.haskell.org/package/jack) on Windows.

I've installed Jack for Windows (from http://jackaudio.org/downloads/). However, regardless of what I set `--extra-lib-dirs` to, I still get a `Missing (or bad) C library: jack` error.

So, even if I run

```
cabal install jack --extra-include-dirs="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jack\includes" --extra-lib-dirs="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jack" --extra-lib-dirs="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jack\lib" --extra-lib-dirs="C:\Windows\jack"
```

I still get the error. Adding the `--extra-include-dirs="..."` part did fix the `Missing (or bad) header file: jack/jack.h` error, though.

I've tried installing pkg-config on the msys installation in `C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\...`, which fixed an error that occurred when I didn't use `-f -pkgconfig`, but otherwise didn't fix anything else. I also tried compiling Jack with MinGW, but I couldn't figure out how.

Is there some location for the library files that I'm missing? Or is there some package for MinGW that has the required library files?

Comment: You could try installing `stack` and using `stack exec pacman` to install jack package.

Comment: @arrowd's approach is exactly what I'd do as well. Unfortunately, Stack's MinGW/MSYS2 distribution doesn't seem to include jack. It also seems that you're using Cabal, which means you wouldn't be able to use that method anyway.